# Which eclipse edition is suitable for client server Java programming

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to implement with Eclipse a client server application in Java but I am confused with which Eclipse edition to use. Is Java EE Developers the solution?

Comment: Usually, you use the Java EE version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, **Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers** is the right choice. Go for the newest stable version **Mars** (4.5).

You can find it [on the download pages](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/mars2) for different operating systems and versions.

Answer (score 0):

theoretically you can develop with any eclipse version which has EE bundles installed, but generally I would use Kepler

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplersr2

Comment: Any reason you would recommend using version Kepler (4.3) rather than the newest stable version Mars (4.5)?

Comment: not really, if you want to write java 8 code, then Mars would be better than Kepler.

Comment: @Arctigor its not kelper who helps to write java 8 code its jdk 1.8 and IDS has nothing to do with it.

Comment: yes, you are right, but you have to install a patch for Kepler in order to use jdk 1.8...Mars will support by default jdk 1.8 and java 8